# concatenating a dataframe row values into one with consistent padding

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've a `dataframe` like below

```
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+
| X | XX | Y | YY | ZZ | ZZZ | ZZZZ |
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+
| 0 |  1 | 1 |  0 |  0 |  1  |   0  |
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+
| 1 |  0 | 0 |  1 |  0 |  0  |   1  |
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+
| 0 |  1 | 0 |  0 |  1 |  0  |   0  |
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+
| 0 |  0 | 1 |  0 |  0 |  0  |   0  |
+---+----+---+----+----+-----+------+

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X':[0,1,0,0],
    'XX':[1,0,1,0],
    'Y':[1,0,0,1],
    'YY':[0,1,0,0],
    'ZZ':[0,0,1,0],
    'ZZZ':[1,0,0,0],
    'ZZZZ':[0,1,0,0]
})
```

I want to concatenate the dataframe `row values` into one with consistent `padding`.

I tried the below code

```
df.dot(df.columns +' | ')
```

`|` sign with extra `spaces before and after`.

what I get is

```
0     XX | Y | ZZZ |
1    X | YY | ZZZZ |
2          XX | ZZ |
3                Y |
dtype: object
```

But, what I expect to receive is

```
0      XX |  Y |  ZZZ |
1       X | YY | ZZZZ |
2           XX |   ZZ |
3                   Y |
        dtype: object
```

notice the alignment in `|` sign.

How can I modify my code to add this extra variable padding spaces? `pandas` or `numpy` solution preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is add space for constant `padding` by maximal length of string in columns names:

```
print (df.columns.str.len().max())
4

df = df.dot(df.columns.str.rjust(df.columns.str.len().max(), ' ') +' | ')
#working like
#df = df.dot(df.columns.str.rjust(4, ' ') +' | ')
print (df)
0      XX |    Y |  ZZZ | 
1       X |   YY | ZZZZ | 
2             XX |   ZZ | 
3                     Y | 
dtype: object
```

Comment: so `4` in `rjust(4, ' ')` method refers to the maximum characters? in this case `ZZZZ` which is `4`?

Comment: @Tommy - Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
g=df.gt(0).columns*df
g.agg(set,1).map(list).str.join('|').str.strip('\w')
```

Comment: there's an error. `cannot perform __mul__ with this index type: Index`.

Comment: Anyways, I like @jezrael answers. It is just a simple tweak to my existing code. Thanks.!

Comment: @Tommy, all the best. Happy coding